# Difficulty of indexing Country, State , City

Tags: mysql, database

Instead of  entering repeated  user location for  several users  who share the same location I am planning to normalize  by giving locationID  from Locations table to each user  in the User table so that I don’t have to enter  Country, State, City repeatedly  in the User table  so I save disk space. (USA, CT, Woodhaven )

After several users say 12th users may enter USA,NY, Albany and this entry is entered in the 12th row in the Locations Table .  When a user enters his locations  information (Country, State, City)  I need to check in Locations table to see if  the record exists before entering the new record.  Problem is that you can’t index State and City columns because it will not match with the country ( Afghanistan , Alabama, Azirben, Country, State and City respectively.

Is there a EFFICIENT way you can sort the State, and City  to be in consistent with alphabetically indexed Country name (I want the  State starting with A and the City starting with A in Afghanistan  to go with Country Afghanistan as the first row and so on assuming Afghanistan is the first country in country list.

I  believe  even though the normalized method having a separate Locations table saves disk space,  time to search the record , insert if not  already in the Locations table and then insert LocationsID in the user table is more costly in terms of  time.  Am I correct in my assertion?

Comment: What do you want to optimize? The `insert` time or the `select` time?

Answer (score 4):

**This is a typical pitfall of normalization in databases: normalizing for the sake of space only.**

Space is cheap.

Think in terms of functional dependencies: the tuple (Country, State, City) is supposed to be the Functional dependency but you don't have any information that depends on it, nor of its components (at least you have not told us). Alternatively you could have certain functional dependencies such State->Country, or City -> Coutry,State (but you already know that this is not the case for a global database).

You could equally have it as a single attribute "Country;State;City" and it would not have affected your design (from a functional dependency point of view; it would have from a searching data point of view).

In other words, you would want to normalize this table if you have any information specific to the tuple (Country, State, City), or you have functional dependencies you want to enforce within the tuple itself.

if you don't, then don't normalize it just for the sake of space. Space has never been the main motivation behind normalization (update/insert/delete anomalies are the main reason).

Put it this way. Would you normalize the first name and last name of a person just for the sake of saving space?

If you still want to do it, then don't worry about how indexes sort the data. That should not be your worry. You can create an tree-based index --the default-- on (Country, State, City) and you can then search for a given country, or a country state, or a country, state, city (you can always use a prefix in a tree-based index). you can create as many indexes as you want on a table with any combination of attributes. But this will take space, and will slow down insertions, but I suspect you won't have many in that table anyways.

**My suggestion, don't normalize this data.**

--dmg

Comment: I was having the exact same thoughts - and unless your DB is going to contain millions and millions of rows with repeating country + state + city combination, there is simply no point of normalizing that. +1 because database normalization is overrated: Maybe [Normalizing Isn't Normal](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html)

Answer (score 1):

In most (next to all) situations the normalized form is the best form. In your example, I would suggest you make a `SELECT` on the combination of city, state, country and see if the new value already exist and if not create the lines before adding the user. That is slightly more costly on insertion time (because you will have two queries) but will reduce your disk usage and selection time.

You should place an index on the city, state and country tables, though.

Be aware that this way you will have duplicate entries for the same place (because `Munich, Bavaria, Germany` is the same as `München, Bayern, Deutschland`, but you will have no chance to know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure "indexing" is your question. If I have understood you correctly, you will have 2 tables:

```
USERS
 - UserID
 - ....
 - LocationID


LOCATIONS
 - LocationID
 - City
 - State
 - Country
```

You can either populate "locations" in advance, from something like [this](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities), or insert new locations into the table as the user enters them. Something like:

```
insert into Locations
values
(null, $city, $state, $country)
where not exists
(select * from locations 
  where city = $city 
  and country = $country 
  and state = $state)
```

and then find the locationID which matches the same criteria to insert into the user table.

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of entering repeated user location for several users who share the same location I am planning to normalize by giving locationID from Locations table to each user in the User table so that I don’t have to enter Country, State, City repeatedly in the User table so I save disk space. (USA, CT, Woodhaven )

What you're describing isn't normalization.

If you *were* trying to normalize your original table, you'd identify a functional dependency, a multi-value dependency, or a join dependency in the original table, and you'd remove that dependency by projection.

But you're not doing that. You're just picking three closely related columns and replacing repeated text with a repeated ID number. And that's not normalizing.

The only possible dependency, given what little you've told us, is that {city, state->country}. Whether that dependency holds is application-dependent, but it doesn't hold on a global scale. If I recall correctly, as of a few years ago there were duplicates in a some Arabic countries and in some Latin American countries.

If, on the other hand, you want an additional table(s) that you can use to increase data integrity, and that application code can use to present sorted possibilities to the user, that's pretty straightforward. But that has to do with data integrity, not with normalization.

You can store countries, states, and cities like this. I'm not recommending you *do* this *exactly*; it's an example. In practice, you should think hard about using ISO country codes.

- [ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1), "Country" codes
- [ISO 3166-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2), "State" codes

.

```
create table countries (
  country_name varchar(35) not null,
  primary key (country_name)
);

create table states (
  country_name varchar(35) not null,
  state_name varchar(35) not null,
  primary key (country_name, state_name),
  foreign key (country_name) 
    references countries (country_name)
);

create table cities (
  country_name varchar(35) not null,
  state_name varchar(35) not null,
  city_name varchar(35) not null,
  primary key (country_name, state_name, city_name),
  foreign key (country_name, state_name)
    references states (country_name, state_name)
);
```

Set a foreign key reference from your table to the table "cities".

Answer (score 0):

You can try also without ajax call and database manage:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Demo by kishan Radadiya</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Countries
        var country_arr = new Array("Select Country","AUSTRALIA","INDIA","NEW ZEALAND","USA","UAE","MAURITIUS");

        $.each(country_arr, function (i, item) {
            $('#country').append($('<option>', {
                value: i,
                text : item,
            }, '</option>' ));
        });

        // States
        var s_a = new Array();
        s_a[0]="Select State";
        s_a[1]="Select State|QUEENSLAND|VICTORIA";
        s_a[2]="Select State|ANDHRAPRADESH|KARNATAKA|TAMILNADU|DELHI|GOA|W-BENGAL|GUJARAT|MADHYAPRADESH|MAHARASHTRA|RAJASTHAN";
        s_a[3]="Select State|AUCKLAND";
        s_a[4]="Select State|NEWJERSEY|ILLINOIS";
        s_a[5]="Select State|DUBAI";
        s_a[6]="Select State|MAURITIUS";

        // Cities
        var c_a = new Array();
        c_a['QUEENSLAND']="BRISBANE";
        c_a['VICTORIA']="MELBOURNE";
        c_a['ANDHRAPRADESH']="HYDERABAD";
        c_a['KARNATAKA']="BANGLORE";
        c_a['TAMILNADU']="CHENNAI";
        c_a['DELHI']="DELHI";
        c_a['GOA']="GOA";
        c_a['W-BENGAL']="KOLKATA";
        c_a['GUJARAT']="AHMEDABAD1|AHMEDABAD2|AHMEDABAD3|BARODA|BHAVNAGAR|MEHSANA|RAJKOT|SURAT|UNA";
        c_a['MADHYAPRADESH']="INDORE";
        c_a['MAHARASHTRA']="MUMBAI|PUNE";
        c_a['RAJASTHAN']="ABU";
        c_a['AUCKLAND']="AUCKLAND";
        c_a['NEWJERSEY']="EDISON";
        c_a['ILLINOIS']="CHICAGO";
        c_a['MAURITIUS']="MAURITIUS";
        c_a['DUBAI']="DUBAI";


        $('#country').change(function(){
            var c = $(this).val();
            var state_arr = s_a[c].split("|");
            $('#state').empty();
            $('#city').empty();
            if(c==0){
                $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select State',
                }, '</option>'));
            }else {
                $.each(state_arr, function (i, item_state) {
                    $('#state').append($('<option>', {
                        value: item_state,
                        text: item_state,
                    }, '</option>'));
                });
            }
            $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                value: '0',
                text: 'Select City',
            }, '</option>'));
        });

        $('#state').change(function(){
            var s = $(this).val();
            if(s=='Select State'){
                $('#city').empty();
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: '0',
                    text: 'Select City',
                }, '</option>'));
            }
            var city_arr = c_a[s].split("|");
            $('#city').empty();

            $.each(city_arr, function (j, item_city) {
                $('#city').append($('<option>', {
                    value: item_city,
                    text: item_city,
                }, '</option>'));
            });


        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="country" id="country"></select> <br>
<select name="state" id="state"></select> <br>
<select name="city" id="city"></select>
</body>
</html>
```